# Replacing some elements in a variable

Tags: r, string, replace, numeric

I have a txt file format. I have some problems about reading and replacing this file.
When I use:

```
mrk <- read.table("mrk.txt", skip = 1, colClasses = c("numeric","character") )
str(mrk)
'data.frame':   1550 obs. of  2 variables:
$ V1: num  22079 21553  ...
$ V2: chr  "0244004434040323042220022240040200322344300043202322322202240023434432420023002200223430420004344023" "0233402242030024022334032220030340022023000034202422423202230024303343223344320303440204030303032323"
```

My problems are:

1-  mrk$ V2 is character. It should be as numeric and similar to string.

2-  I should replace 3 and 4 to 1:

```
mrk$V2[mrk$V2=="3"]<-"1"
mrk$V2[mrk$V2=="4"]<-"1"
```

It does not work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `gsub` for the replacment

```
V2 <- c("0244004434040323042220022240040200322344300043202322322202240023434432420023002200223430420004344023",
        "0233402242030024022334032220030340022023000034202422423202230024303343223344320303440204030303032323")

V2 <- gsub("[3|4]", "1", V2)
as.numeric(V2)
#[1] 2.110011e+98 2.111022e+98
```

But you might consider to change the argument `colClasses` from `c("numeric", "character")` to `c("numeric", "numeric")`. when reading your data into R.